# Core Data Request issue

Tags: objective-c, core-data, request, data-modeling

I've a data model and i have an issue for executing a request.

Here's my model :

[image]

I would like to get all the expenses associated to one specific event.

Do you think that my model is wrong ?

For more explanations this is how i set my data in the data base :
I have **2 types** of ***event*** : *'Event'* and *'Party'*

A ***guest*** is associated to **1 or n** expenses and an expense is associated to **1 or n** guests.
Thats why i've created my entity "Transaction".

A ***transaction*** has 2 types : "*Paid*" and "*Beneficied*" because a ***Guest*** can pay an expense and can  be a beneficiary too.

Here's how i work with theses entities :
For **one** *expense* in **one** *event*, a *guest* pays this *expense* for all the other *guests*, so i create a *transaction* associated to **this** *guest* and **the** *expense* with the type '*Paid*' and a **has many transactions as** my *event's guests* associated to **the same** *expense* but with the type "*Beneficied*".

I don't know i'm very clear in my explonations...

***EDIT***

As people doesn't really understand my question, i'll explain how my application does work.

The main purpose of my application is to **rebalance expenses** between people for a *party* (birthday, sushi party, etc.) or an *event* (vacations, week-end, etc.).

My application is already on the Apple store : **iVent**.
But it doesn't works very well that's why i want to update it using core data :).

So, how doest it work ?

The user create an event and select the **type** of the event

***For a party :***

I get the iPhone contact and show them on a tableview, **the user check which contact is invited to the party.**

Then **for each event**, i have a **Grocery list**. I get that **grocery list from a plist** which can be modify by the user as "Default grocery list". But, for each event, the user can delete all the groceries, *it won't affect the plist*.

My groceries are sorted by **categories** (Drinks, meals, furnitures, alcohols, etc.).
The user selects **which grocery** he wants for example *2 six-packs, 3 bottle of Red wine etc.*
Then he **links a Grocery to a Guest** : Paul will buy 1 six-packs and 1 bottle of red wine, Amy 1 six-pack etc.

Then i allow the user to ***give the price for each assigned groceries*** and to set ***which guest is beneficiary for this grocery.***
For example Anna doesn't drink alcohol, so she doesn't want to pay for any alcohol when the user will rebalance all the price between the user.

***For an event, the process is different :***

The user **only check the invited guest** for the event creation.
Then during the event *the user will put in the data base all the expenses made*.

For exemple Paul and Anna **paid gas for everyone**, so we set Paul and Anna **as buyers of an expense** and Paul, Anna, Maurice and Mike ***as beneficiary*** because they all were in the car for the trip.

We can set different prices for **the buyers** for example the gas cost 50$ then Anna paid 20$ and Mike 30$.

It's the same for the **beneficiaries** : For example Mike came only at middle of the trip so he will pay (after the rebalance) only 12.5% of the price for the gas and not 25% as default
(because they were 4 in the car ^^)

I know it's a little confusing to understand but that's why i came here for help ^^

Basically that's how my application works, the version on the Appstore does already all of these features but not very well.

Here's my all data model :

[image]

I hope you'll understand now my problem :)

I'd like to know **if my model is Ok** and **how can i list all the expenses for an Event** (not a party) with this model configuration.

Comment: This is not clear at all. Could you go into the purpose of the application as a whole? It might help people understand what you are asking for exactly

Comment: Ok i'll edit my question and explain how my application works :)

Comment: So here's what I'm understanding. You want to give the "Event" entity some way to access "Expense" entities? Why not create a relationship between event and expense?

Comment: @Pinwheeler Doesn't this make a redundancy ? 
Because for a "party", i have a category and a Grocery but not for an "Event"

Comment: Okay, I'm understanding you more and more. Right now, if you want to have an 'Event' have an 'Expense', it must first have a 'Guest' and that 'Guest' must have a 'Transaction'. Currently, there is no way for your 'Event' to have an 'Expense' on its own. Is this as intended?

Comment: @Pinwheeler Yes it's ! But transaction is created automatically with an expense! I use the transaction to differentiate the link between an Expense and a Guest when the guest is the buyers of the expense and when he's the beneficiary of it! That's why i have an attribute "Type" in "Transaction" : Beneficied or Paid transaction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think what I'm hearing is that your model looks good. If you want a list of all of the expenses associated with an Event you'll have to go through the guests. The following is pseudocode since I'm not exactly sure on the syntax

```
NSMutableArray* expenseList; //This will contain all of the expense objects for a given event
   for Guest* guestObject in myEvent.guests
   {
      for Transaction* transactionObject in guestObject.transactions
      {
          [expenseList addObject:transactionObject.expense];
      }
   }
```

Comment: I've resolved my problem adding a relation between Event and Expense :)
But this code works too ^^
Thanks @Pinwheeler !